# onAttach is not called

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have one activity and two fragments, Frag_1 and Frag_2. in both fragments i override onAttach method and there is a log message inside each onAttach method. when I run 
the App, the log message in the onAttach method of the Frag_1 is displayed while the log message in onAttach method in Frag_2 is never displayed. actually, I want to 
know why the onAttach in Frag2 is not called because I initialize an instance of an interface inside it.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    iValuePasser = (IValuePasser) activity;
}
```

please let me know why the onAttch callbak is never called.

**note** App API level is 21

Comment: Did you try "public void onAttach(Context context)"? (The one you posted is deprecated)

Comment: @kikettas but when i changed it to (Context context), onattach is never called in neither Frag_1 nor Frag_2

Comment: Well you can still use this deprecated, if you target below 23.Use support library v4 for this

Answer (score 0):

Fragment have two methods called "onAttach" one of them was deprecated as documentation said [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

```
// you should override this
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    //Deprecated

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }
```